# Repeated close visits on US Visa Waiver Programme

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I recently spent 2 weeks in the US for a friend's wedding and a bit of a holiday.  I am a British citizen and travelled with no issues under the vwp.

However, having discovered I am able to take some time away from work I would like to see a bit more of the country and spend some time with friends and relatives and planned a visit of around 80-90 or so days from mid December. I would not be working nor would I go over my 90 days!

I would have proof that I could support myself whist there, proof of a place to stay in England and in the US, proof that I have a job and a car to go back to and also obviously my return ticket.

Do you think I will have any issue getting into the US for my longer trip with it only having been 6 weeks since the trip before?  I have been reading horror stories online and it is making me very anxious.

Does anyone know of anyone actually being sent back on the next flight back at border control?  Has any one had any issues at border control and what caused those (trip too long or close together??)

Any advice much appreciated as I would hate to pay for a flight and then get turned away!  I think I am just being paranoid but thought I would check!

Comment: I once entered the US twice in 14 days, having been back to Europe in between! No problems re-entering, but I seem to recall getting a look best described as "confused pity" from the immigration guy when he saw how recently I'd last entered + I'd just come off a flight from the UK...

Comment: Ah thank you! It is totally genuine and I have a job, car and home to come back to I just want to spend some time with people and take advantage of a break from work.  I thought the same re actually getting turned back.  Though I have seen lots of mention that this "could" happen and it's all down to the customs official etc I haven't actually seen any evidence.

My worry was more that I wanted to stay for 85 ish days and I know that raises some questions but really if I have a return ticket and I am legally allowed to be there for 90 days it shouldn't be an issue :)

Comment: Gagravarr, can I ask how long you stayed for your 2nd visit?  It is the length of time I wish to stay that's freaking me out.  If I was only going for 2 weeks I wouldn't worry but I really want to take advantage of the 90 days to explore.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are now in England, traveling back there reset your 90 days. Is your ESTA still valid? If so, come on back. You should be able to travel back to the US under the VWP, with your ESTA, and stay for up to 90 days.

You might also want to double check that your I-94 record was updated correctly. You should be able to check it at the US Customs and Border Protection's [I-94 verification page](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/request.html;jsessionid=6ktXJjGTyR95VhtNZy2jblLcMfk0szp1hBqVVTWdny0Qdz6SqGpg!-1326691254).

Comment: Yes, I came back on the 5th Nov.  I am looking at flights just now and hope to travel before Christmas to enjoy that time over there.  I actually checked the I-94 and it was all adjusted accordingly.  I guess times would be bad if they were genuinely discouraging travellers from visiting America.  I never went travelling at 18, I have always worked.  This is my big adventure for a few months at the age of 31.  Haha! Thanks for getting back to me : )

Comment: And yes, I applied for my ESTA in October this year so it should be valid until 2016.  I was under the impression you didn't need to apply again for multiple visits and that it would automatically come up as attached to my passport number etc for the remainder of the 2 years.

Comment: @Hannah Never assume, [check your ESTA here as well](https://www.esta-america.org/verify-esta.html).